# Fabric JS Select Object by ID Programmatically

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In Fabric JS I need to select object by given object Name/ID "Circle"

```
var onCircle = function () {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ id: 'Circle', radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 150, left: 150 }));
}
```

I also know the object can able to select by ItemID:

```
var SelectObject = function (ObjectName) 
{
    canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
}
```

I need something like:

```
var SelectObject = function (ObjectName) 
{
    canvas.setActiveObject('my object name');
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you just need to write a function to loop though each object and set it as active when you find it. Below I check id but you can change it to check any property on the object you want to set.

```
var SelectObject = function (ObjectName) {
    canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(o) {
        if(o.id === ObjectName) {
            canvas.setActiveObject(o);
        }
    })
}
```