# How to select programmatically one image within set of images in Fabric.js rendered

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

There are multiple images in the canvas
how to select one programmatically in fabric js

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(this.imageSrc, (img) => {
      let oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
      }).scale(1);
this.canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an image to a variable like this:

```js
var oImg;
fabric.Image.fromURL(this.imageSrc, (img) => {
  oImg = img.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    angle: 0
  });
  canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
});
```

Since the image object is now stored as `oImg`, you can select it like this:

```
canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
```

Or, you can select objects in the canvas based on their index like this:

```
var obj = canvas.item(0);
canvas.setActiveObject(obj);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer .is there any way of using id for that?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191597/fabric-js-select-object-by-id-programmatically/40196417

Comment: Actually I need to do some photoshop like layer listing and order changing for images with canvas is there any way of using this fabricjs or any recommendation.?